# How to download chunked file with NodeJs POST request?

Tags: node.js, axios

i got a problem here.

Lets start from we have API, this API returns data with next headers:

```
Content-Type image/png
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Connection keep-alive
```

And response body where only file is.

When im try to write this body data into file - it's always broken. I mean i've binary data, his mime, body.length is match original filesize, but this image could not be opened in any viewer after i save it.

What i'm do:

```
public userFile(req, res: Response) {
    const data = {
        fileId: parseInt(req.body.fileId),
    };

    let params = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': keys.token,
        },
    };


    axios.post('/api/getfile/', data, params,)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
            const fs = require('fs');
            const dir = require('path').resolve(__dirname + '../../../files/storage');
          
            const ext = {
                'image/png': '.png'
            };

            fs.writeFile(dir + '/' + img + ext[response.headers['content-type']], response.data, (er) => {
                res.send(response.data);
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            logger.error("AXIOS ERROR: ", err)
        })
}
```

BUT! When i get this file with postman... here it is!
So, i need your help - what i do wrong?

Comment: what's the error you getting?

Comment: saved file is broken. But when i do same with postman - file is received fine.

What is postman get: https://imgur.com/a/YIo1wGJ (yeah, this image just part of other response, so seems its an error but it not :) )

What i get: https://imgur.com/a/WA1i2w9

Comment: try to use   ```responseType: 'stream'``` in params and 
 ````response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/dir/xyz.png"))````

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: god bless you it's work! I tried the same, but like response.pipe, who knows that i shoud use data.pipe. Thank you!

Comment: also, where to read more about this features in axios? Is there some events, how i know that data is finally uploaded?

Comment: you should read the official axios docs and git examples. i have answered the question please mark it as correct

Comment: you should check response code received if it's 200 then it's very likely successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specifically declare which response type it is in params as

```
responseType: 'stream'
```

then save stream to a file using pipe

```
response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/dir/xyz.png"))
```